# Play app can't run after adding scalacOptions in SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

I've added these Scalac options in my SBT build:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation","-feature"),
```

But then I can't access my Play 2.1 web application anymore.

It is the only modified part of my build, and if I remove this, it works fine again.

It's weird because the application seems to be running (I see startup logs, scheduled jobs...), but trying to access it from the browser gives me Play error page:

```
Cannot init the Global object
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
     Global$.<init>(Global.scala:17)
     Global$.<clinit>(Global.scala)
     sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
     sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
     sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:949)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:930)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:372)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$scalaGlobal(Application.scala:37)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$scalaGlobal$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$scalaGlobal(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Application.scala:52)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Application.scala:52)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:52)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:51)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:50)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.global(Application.scala:66)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.global(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:80)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration$lzycompute(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.configuration(Application.scala:82)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.configuration(Application.scala:383)
     play.api.Application$class.$init$(Application.scala:268)
     play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:383)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:114)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112)
     play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My Global.scala looks like this:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  // TODO use cake pattern injection?
  val searchService: SearchService = StampleApplication.get.searchService
  val breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService = StampleApplication.get.breadcrumbService

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
    startElasticSearchIndexationScheduling
    startBreadcrumbUpdaterJob
  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }



  // TODO externaliser delais des jobs dans la conf play?

  def startElasticSearchIndexationScheduling = {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(30 seconds , 30 seconds) {
      Logger.info("Indexation job triggered")
      searchService.indexUnindexedStamples
      searchService.indexUnindexedUsers
    }
  }

  def startBreadcrumbUpdaterJob = {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(30 seconds, 30 seconds) {
      Logger.info("Breadcrumb updated job triggered")
      breadcrumbService.updateChildsBreadcrumbForFlaggedCategories
      Logger.info("Breadcrumb updated (with recursion!) job triggered")
      breadcrumbService.recompteAllFlaggedWithRecursion
    }
  }



}
```

The Global$.(Global.scala:17) seems to reference this line:

```
val searchService: SearchService = StampleApplication.get.searchService
```

The rest of the sources are:

```
object StampleApplication {

  val get: CakeApplication = {
    println("Building stample cake application")
    // Inject properties here
    new CakeConfiguration().buildApplication
  }

}

trait CakeApplication
  extends ServiceLayer
  with RepositoryLayer


trait ServiceLayer
  extends RepositoryLayer
  with DefaultUserServiceComponent
  with DefaultCategoryServiceComponent
  with DefaultStampleServiceComponent
  with DefaultAclServiceComponent
  with DefaultFileServiceComponent
  with DefaultApiCallServiceComponent
  with DefaultBreadcrumbServiceComponent
  with DefaultSearchServiceComponent
  with DefaultRelationshipServiceComponent
  with DefaultSharingServiceComponent
  with DefaultAuthCodeServiceComponent
  with DefaultNotificationServiceComponent
  with DefaultEventServiceComponent
  with DefaultCommentServiceComponent


trait RepositoryLayer
  extends MongoUserRepositoryComponent
  with MongoCategoryRepositoryComponent
  with MongoCategorySharingRepositoryComponent
  with MongoStampleRepositoryComponent
  with MongoFileRepositoryComponent
  with MongoApiCallRepositoryComponent
  with MongoRelationshipRepositoryComponent
  with MongoSharingRepositoryComponent
  with MongoNotificationRepositoryComponent

  with SalatDAOFactoryComponent
  with CollectionProviderComponent

trait CollectionProviderComponent {
  def collectionProvider:MongoCollectionProvider
}
```

Comment: I added the same line to my `Build.scala` but I don't get any errors (just compiler warnings as expected with the new options added) when running/compiling. It seems to be complaining about your `Global.scala` class so maybe you can show it?

Comment: @maba i've added all I can

Comment: I don't really understand why your application would behave differently with only that scalac change. What you can try out as a fix (without really knowing the actual problem with that line) is to make the `searchService` lazy by just writing `lazy val searchService: SearchService = StampleApplication.get.searchService`.